# Ruled lines on the bottom half of each page?

Tags: header-footer, rules

I'm trying to typeset a version of a document that will have the document on the half of each page, but I want the bottom half to have thin ruled lines for note taking. Any one have any thoughts about how I could do this automatically? Could I some how make a custom footer for each page?

Answer (score 6):

In ConTeXt, the page layout has a parameter `bottom` that goes below the footer. You can set its value just like the value of a footer. That way, you can still have your regular footers and put anything else at the bottom of the page. Here is a complete solution:

```
\setuplayout
  [height=fit,
   bottomdistance=1in,
   bottom=4.8in]

\startsetups bottom:rule
  \vbox
    {\dorecurse{32}{\blackrule[width=\textwidth,height=1pt]\blank[12pt]}}
\stopsetups

\setupbottomtexts[\setups{bottom:rule}]

\showframe
\starttext
\dorecurse{10}{\input knuth \par}
\stoptext
```

In `\setuplayout` the option `bottom=4.8in` allocates 4.8in for the bottom. The bottom area is placed 1in from the bottom of the text area (option `bottomdistance=1in`). The option `height=fit` asks ConTeXt to recalculate the height of the text area so that everything fits on the page.

The `\setupbottomtexts` sets what should be printed in the bottom area (this is just like `\setupfootertexts` for footers). The setups mechanism is just a nice way to abstract out complicated pieces of code.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want the 'document on one half of each page' to look like, you might be able to use `pgfpages`, as in http://www.guidodiepen.nl/2009/07/creating-latex-beamer-handouts-with-notes/. This approach will work if you want existing pages of the document to be scaled down to half the page size.

Otherwise I would use `geometry` to create a large bottom margin, and then something like `atbegshi` to add the ruled lines to each page (`\AtBeginShipout{...}`)